# print variable 1 or variable 2 depending on if the variable 1 is set or not

Tags: php

I want to `echo` variable `$a` if it is set, or `echo` variable `$b` if variable `$a` was not set.

I tried something, but it doesn't work as expected:

```
  <?
    $a = "FOO";
    $b = "BAR";
    $c = $a OR $b;
    echo $c; #output : FOO

    //

    $a = false;
    $b = "BAR";
    $c = $a OR $b;
    echo $c; #output : 
  ?>
```

I can do it using a function, like

```
   function F($a,$b) {
      if($a) return $a;
      return $b;
   }
```

or using this:

```
   $c = $a ? $a : $b;
```

but **maybe there is a better way to do this. I want the fastest way to accomplish this.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the closest to what you are trying to do:

```
$c = $a ?: $b;
```

(It is similar to `$c = $a || $b` in JavaScript.)

Note that this assumes the variables are actually set. If they aren't set (i.e., don't exist at all), you should really use `isset`.

Answer (score 1):

You ask the right `if it is set` <-- `isset()`

so

> $c = isset($a) ? $a : isset($b) ? $b : 'Both not set';

Answer (score 1):

according to me  $c = $a ? $a : $b; is the best way